# Hotkey combination to un-snap windows in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

The subject line is the question.  I have found only one combination that
seems to work in all situations, i.e, whether a window
has been snapped to full screen, to one side, or to one corner:

```
Cursor Up
Cursor Up
Cursor Down
```

Easy and quick enough to do, but conceptually, a rather round-about
way to un-snap.  Is there a more direct way?